# Forcing haskell-indent-mode over haskell-indentation-mode in haskell-mode 2.7?

Tags: emacs, haskell, indentation

I'm an Emacs user with no skills with regards to configuring the editor. After I upgraded from [haskell-mode](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs) 2.4 to 2.7, I've noticed two changes:

- Indentation is *different* somehow, in a way I don't quite like. I can't quite put my finger on what it is.
- More importantly: If I have cua-mode enabled and highlight a block of text, backspace/delete does *not* delete the entire block, just the previous/next character from my marker.

I see that haskell-mode 2.7 uses the minor mode haskell-indentation-mode by default, while 2.4's behaviour has been preserved in the form of haskell-indent-mode. If I first turn off the former, and then on the latter, the behaviour I want is restored (i.e. indentation feels like before, and backspace/delete deletes highlighted blocks).

I can't, however, get this to happen automatically whenever I open a file with a .hs suffix. I've tried various things resembling

```
(remove-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indent-mode)
```

and the likes of it, but I either end up with the standard mode or with plain haskell-mode without indent and doc.

Any ideas?

**Solution (thanks to nominolo)**:

```
(remove-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indent)
(remove-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'my-haskell-mode-hook)
(defun my-haskell-mode-hook ()
   (haskell-indentation-mode -1) ;; turn off, just to be sure
   (haskell-indent-mode 1)       ;; turn on indent-mode
   )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to configure such things is by writing a custom hook:

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'my-haskell-mode-hook)

(defun my-haskell-mode-hook ()
   (haskell-indentation-mode -1) ;; turn off, just to be sure
   (haskell-indent-mode 1)       ;; turn on indent-mode

   ;; further customisations go here.  For example:
   (setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8 )
   (flyspell-prog-mode)  ;; spell-checking in comments and strings
   ;; etc.      

   )
```

You could also stick an anonymous function in there, but having a named function is easier if you want to experiment with some settings.  Just redefining the function (and re-opening a Haskell file) will give you the new behaviour.

Comment: Great answer; this is much better than the pattern of random `add-hook`s I had before. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help for me. I add the code you gave to my .emacs, but when I open a .hs haskell-indentation-mode is still on. Running `M-x haskell-indentation-mode` turns it off as expected.

Comment: @gspr: It could be that you have another hook running after.  Use `C-h v haskell-mode-hook` to see the active hooks.  Alternatively, it seems there are actually three indentation modes, so maybe you need to turn another mode off?

Comment: Ah, great, that helps a lot! Turns out `my-haskell-mode-hook` was before `turn-on-haskell-indent` and `turn-on-haskell-indentation`.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote btw. Apparently I did, and then removed it again (by accident), and now it says my vote is locked.